# FullCalendar does not render date for month and day view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Following Data is being passed about events:

```
[{"title":"my First Entry","start":"2016-09-27T11:47:00","end":"2016-09-27T12:47:00","allday":false}]
```

It renders entry only in `month` view. `eventRender` is also not fired for `day` and `week`

**Javascript**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        events: "http://localhost:8000/fetch",
        // events: [
        //     {
        //         title: 'Lunch with All',
        //         start: new Date(2016, 9, 27, 12, 0),
        //         end: new Date(2016, 9, 27, 13, 0),
        //         allDay: false
        //     },
        //     {
        //         title: 'Birthday Party',
        //         start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        //         end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        //         allDay: false
        //     },
        //     {
        //         title: 'Click for Google',
        //         start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        //         end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        //         url: 'http://google.com/'
        //     }
        // ],

        // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            var start = event.start;
            console.log("Rendered");

            var end = moment(event.end);
            event.end = end;
            if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                event.allDay = true;
            } else {
                event.allDay = false;
            }
        },
        selectable: false,
        selectHelper: false,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
            if (title) {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
                    data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&url=' + url,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (json) {
                        alert('Added Successfully');
                    }
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        editable: false,
        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (json) {
                    alert("Updated Successfully");
                }
            });
        },
        eventResize: function (event) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (json) {
                    alert("Updated Successfully");
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

It works fine for all views if date is set in this format `new Date(2016, 9, 27, 12, 0)`

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I've copied the entire code with the data you've posted at the beggining [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/ueLa76rc/)) and it all seems to, including the event render (as you get the console log). Can you provide a fiddle that replicates your issue? Also, the commented events array is not a valid JSON (not sure if this matters to the question).

Comment: @milz If you notice entries does not appear in all views(day, week)

Comment: I honestly don't understand what the issue is.. The fiddle shows the event both on month, week and day view, as you can see on this screenshots: [month](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=57aff27), [week](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=813be55) and [day](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=39a98d6). Please clarify your issue.

Comment: @milz http://imgur.com/a/1SmQW This entry appears in month view though(http://imgur.com/a/4GQRP)

Comment: What?! 1. There's a single event on the calendar for **2016-09-27** from 11:47 to 12:47. 2. The month view of October also displays the last week of September (and this is why you see an event) and the first week of November. 3. There is no event on the **2016-10-27** so there's nothing to display.4. This is a non-issue and I'm voting to close this question.